# Heroku 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, routes

I deployed a PHP application and when I hit the url, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I guess it tries to go into the app/ directory but it can't.

---

My project structure:

```
my-project
|
|-> app/
|-> public/ (index.php inside here that takes care of routing)
Procfile
composer.json
etc.
```

---

What the log shows:

```
Jul 24 12:44:08 cryptic-beyond-39147 app/web.1:  [Sun Jul 24 19:44:07.846582 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 99:tid 139960748263168] [client 10.179.164.130:28253] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive 
Jul 24 12:44:08 cryptic-beyond-39147 app/web.1:  10.179.164.130 - - [24/Jul/2016:19:44:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36 
Jul 24 12:44:13 cryptic-beyond-39147 heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-beyond-39147.herokuapp.com request_id=9b5e81de-440b-4001-90a4-bc94ee891d3c fwd="89.210.178.134" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=373
```

---

Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

---

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems that Heroku wants a `Procfile` to have the `public` directory in there, whatever your public foldername is. Probably you can omit the file if you have an index.php in project root.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ehhmm so I found the solution.

My Procfile had a .txt extension (so Procfile.txt) whereas it needs to be only Procfile.

Quit a silly mistake but I thought I should leave the answer here for future reference. Maybe it will save time from someone else.

Comment: just incase you are still having this issue, the file name is also case sensitive. `Procfile` not `procfile` took 2 hours to figure that. don't be me

Comment: Thanks for leave the response

Comment: @RaymondAtivie comment is what helped me. For some reason, I thought the file was called Profile!!

Answer (score 5):

I was also having the same problem because I was not having any index.php file in the root folder so I did not get anything, resulting in that error. If you have same problem then after the heroku app url just type your homepage php file. For example - app/custom.php .

Answer (score 1):

A really, simple, and  small solution: the

> ProcFile

name. I named as ProcFile that was the issue rename **ProcFile** to **Procfile** only first letter capital.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and that was solved by creating index.php file.

Comment: @jmoerdyk - It's actually a valid answer for the symptom in the question.

Comment: @ юра снітар - But you should explain why this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely strange error!
Procfile wasn't the cause of issue for me.

For some reason, it fixed when I made an empty directory called "app" inside my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

In my index.php I was using `include_once('index.html')`

Changed to `header('Location: /index.html')` and it works.

Note index.php and index.html are both on root directory.