# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this xampp server while hosting laravel app in heroku

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, heroku, xampp

I try to deploy my laravel app to heroku but while running heroku after completing all steps it show the following error
[image]

My ht access file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does the server have the right privileges to read and create temporary files in the app directory?

Comment: I am using xampp server... I have access to create temporary files

Comment: Be sure to add `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Yes, you have access, but... what about the user running the server?

Comment: Is this issue related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38556113/1144627 by chance? What do your error log files show?

Comment: @fyrye  yes the same issue but where the procfile is located

Comment: @Amarnasan  yes the server is running

Comment: The server is running, but maybe the user of the server (which probable it's not you) doesn't hace the needed privileges

Comment: What @Amarnasan is trying to point out is Apache runs as a certain user and user group, normally `apache`, `www`, or `web` That user group needs permission commonly done on Linux with `chgrp -R apache /path/to/web` Then with `find /path/to/web -type d -exec chmod +rx {} \;`. For procfile see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php#the-procfile

Comment: See the solution to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538467/5527105)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Procfile 
By default, Heroku will launch an Apache web server together with PHP to serve applications from the root directory of the project.
However, your application’s document root is the public/ subdirectory, so you need to create a Procfile that configures the correct document root:

On terminal of project directory, perform following (for Windows)

```
  echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile
```

then do Git add, Commit, Push
 -Source Heroku Documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here：

```
access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
 </Directory>

 <Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

The key point is

```
Require all denied
```

You should change the denied to granted

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the app on Heroku correctly? Can you check whether you did the following things?

1. Create Heroku App
2. Create Procfile On Root Directory Of Project
3. Modify composer.json
4. Get Your Project Files Up-to-date
5. Add Your Project Files To Heroku
6. Setup Database Connections *

If you have missed any step, do it and try again. The complete guidance to *Deploy, Build, Run, and Operate Laravel Applications On Heroku Cloud Application Platform* is included in the following blog article with all the steps and information you need.

Read: [Laravel: Deploy Laravel Projects On Heroku](https://www.ashenlive.com/blog/laravel-deploy-laravel-projects-on-heroku)

https://www.ashenlive.com/blog/laravel-deploy-laravel-projects-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found a solution. It is about Heroku can't find an index file (index.php,index.html) in the directory.
For example, if you can't reach files under the root directory, you should add an index file there. In my case, I had a root directory and had an index.php file so I could reach the files in it. But also there was another folder under the root directory which I couldn't enter. So I created an empty index.html file there too.

Then the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

**in Procfile you have edit it and replace the code to**

```
web: heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

*now update your Procfile by this commend in cmd*

1. git status
2. git add -A
3. git commit -m "Add Procfile and make use of Apache2"
4. git push heroku master

**I hope it will be fixed**