# Laravel 5.4 on Heroku. Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, heroku, laravel-5.4

I have deployed my laravel 5.4 app on Heroku. The problem is, I am getting this error message:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server**

**My Procfile:**

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Looking into the log, I find that it has been trying 'app/' instead of '/'.

**My log**, snipped for readability.

```
2017-12-03T14:18:45.747195+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sun Dec 03 14:18:45.746749 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 122:tid 140692458305280] [client 10.140.221.43:41026] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

**My .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteC
```

I can't figure out where i might be saying it to look into **'app/'** instead of **'/'**. If that is the cause for this error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know why the server thinks your root is at `/app` but this error occurs because of the permission of the `public/` directory from which Heroku is supposed to serve your application.

To resolve this issue, simply add the following to the `script` section of your `composer.json`

```
 "post-install-cmd": [
     "php artisan clear-compiled",
     "chmod -R 777 public/"
 ]
```

Note the change in permission of the `public/` directory.

**EDIT:**

While you are at it, check your `Procfile` make sure it is spelled correctly and starts with an uppercase `P`.

PS: I know some people are really nitpicky and would say the permission is too lax. Yes, I agree with you. You can change it to something else like `775` let's just get the juice flowing.

Comment: i have added the following code to my composer.json. I have also found a solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704032/symfony-on-heroku-403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s] that said to properly name the Procfile. But i still have the error message

Comment: Please check the spelling of your Procfile name. Make sure it is spelled correctly and starts with an uppercase P.

Comment: I also tried  "chmod -R 777 app/storage" by adding cmd command to have permission on storage dir, same error displays.

Comment: I have also tried this solution but the error persisted.

Comment: @trustidkid me too

Answer (score 12):

Inside the Laravel Root folder, make a file called Procfile.

Write the following line inside the Procfile.

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx public/
```

Then deploy it again!
Src and more here https://appdividend.com/2018/04/17/how-to-deploy-laravel-project-on-heroku/

Hope this was helpful =)

Comment: To generate this, make sure you use command exactly as: [echo web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ > Procfile]      without any quotes, in project dir. Quotes do cause this error.

Answer (score 6):

SOLUTION STEPS:

1. Clone your project to your PC:
   **heroku git:clone -a** your-app-name
2. Create a file name: **Procfile**
3. Then **save** following lin of code in this **Procfile**:  `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`
4. Deploy your project back to heroku using commed:
   `$ git add .`
   `$ git commit -am "make it better"`
   `$ git push heroku master`
5. I hope now no problem run your Laravel App!

Answer (score 3):

`/app` is the absolute path on the file system, where you app resides. The error indicates that your `Procfile` does not actually contain what you claim it does. You probably haven't added and committed it to Git. Apache is trying to serve from the "root" right now, not from the `public/` subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

**Create and put this .htaccess file in your laravel installation folder.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

solution is Here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/29748893#29748893)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in Laravel 7.x hosting on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today, and have found an easy solution to it. I'm running a Laravel 6 app on Heroku.

The issue started after I setup an HTTPS redirect, by adding an apache configuration file, and loading it using the -C option in the Heroku Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C apache.conf public/
```

The error I was receiving:

```
2020-01-13T03:55:29.272349+00:00 app[web.1]: [Mon Jan 13 03:55:29.271704 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 127:tid 140227477751552] [client 10.213.231.122:26179] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

So the same issue as you were having. What I found was that when you start apache with a custom configuration on Heroku, it starts looking for an index.html file, instead of an index.php file.

**To fix this, I added the following line to my apache configuration file:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This directs apache to look for index.php, and fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the quotation mark that surrounded the text of the procfile file and it works

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Procfile

from

```
"web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/"
```

to

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Answer (score 0):

This error persist even though i have followed the answer which is marked correct
(even i have run `heroku run bash` to `ls -l` to see the file permission)
but i was still getting this error and may be this is because i was using different local branch rather than the local master branch so my advice is to always deploy from your local master branch  and also when i deploy from another branch i get this log when pushing the code to heroku

```
 NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: heroku-php-apache2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when deploying my Laravel app on Heroku. I tried to change permissions in/of my composer file, but that didn't help. Instead, I added this to my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Pushing this to Heroku fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created `Procfile` using `echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/" > Procfile` command just like the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel) told me to, but then it generated the `Procfile` command inside a quotation mark. That's why, I still get the 403 forbidden error even though I've modified my `composer.json` file just like the other user suggested to.

So guys, make sure the command inside your `Procfile` isn't surrounded by quotation mark. Then, modify the `composer.json` just like the approved answer suggested to and re-deploy your site.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, ensure that the `procfile` is named `Procfile` with the capital `P`.