# Heroku url returns forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, paas

I am actively using github action to do CI/CD of my laravel app, which have always been successful using the workflow.yml below

```
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database
        touch database/database.sqlite
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
      run: vendor/bin/phpunit
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 # This is the action
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: ${{secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME}} #Must be unique in Heroku
          heroku_email: ${{secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL}}
      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

but a the site returns `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.` what could i be missing, i already added .htaccess and Procfile to my root directory and yet still not working.

**Note**: Am trying to use the laravel as my REST API for mobile app application.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619860/laravel-5-4-on-heroku-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s

Comment: Yes i did that already inside my composer.json