# 403 Forbidden Error: What It Is and How to Fix It

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access my page from the web browser. Then suddenly, the webserver is starting to show me the failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden) error. Isn’t it frustrating to experience this? I am all excited and the energy is getting wasted. But How can I recover the error?

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const proceed = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
        if(proceed){
            const url = `https://blooming-lowlands-86443.herokuapp.com/perfume/${id}`;
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const remaining = myPerfume.filter(perfume => perfume._id !== id);
                setMyPerfume(remaining);
            })
        }
  }
```

Comment: Where do you host your server?

Comment: @EldarB. it looks to be heroku by that url.

Comment: Are you using a procfile? [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556113/heroku-403-forbidden-error)

Comment: @EldarB. I hosted my server in heroku.

Comment: Could this be a Heroku misconfiguration then? Try providing the response body, and maybe the relevant back-end code if you can.